# How to display categorical values on export tree image of decision tree classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart, entropy

I am trying to export the decision tree as an image with the original labels of all categorical fields.

The current data I have is like so:

[image]

I transformed the categorical features into numerical:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:4]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lb = LabelEncoder()

X['Outlook'] = lb.fit_transform(X['Outlook'])
X['Temp'] = lb.fit_transform(X['Temp'])
X['Humidity'] = lb.fit_transform(X['Humidity'])
X['Windy'] = lb.fit_transform(X['Windy'])
y = lb.fit_transform(y)
```

Afterwards, I applied the `DecisionTreeClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")
dtc.fit(X, y)
```

At the end, I needed to check the tree generated from the model using the following:

```
# Import tools needed for visualization
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydot
# Pull out one tree from the forest
# Export the image to a dot file
export_graphviz(dtc, out_file = 'tree.dot', feature_names = X.columns, rounded = True, precision = 1)
# Use dot file to create a graph
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')
# Write graph to a png file
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

The `tree.png`:

[image]

But what I really need, is to see the main labels of each feature inside the nodes or at each branch, instead of `true` or `false` or a numeric representation.

I tried the following:

```
y=lb.inverse_transform(y)
```

And the same for X features, but the tree is being generated the same as above.